# Is auto share supported in iOS's twitter framework?

Tags: ios5, twitter

I have a button called twitter,when I click this normally a view is presented for tweeting i.e.`TWTweetComposeViewController` . I have two ways of tweeting a message i.e. auto-share and normal share.Normal share is working perfectly but I have the doubt on how to do the same in auto-share means automatically tweet some default message when I click twitter button instead of showing the `TWTweetComposeViewController` view and click on done button.

Comment: yeah it is possible use tweet sheet

Comment: [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"type what should be auto shared"];

Comment: tweetSheet is the object of TWTweetComposeViewController na?

Comment: @iShru tweetSheet is the object of TWTweetComposeViewController na?

Comment: That is happening but without showing that sheet I need to send the message @iShru

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I searched so many questions related to Twitter in ios5 and also read in twitter Developer Document and tried this answer.I think this is one of the solution to do auto share.

```
ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

        // Request access from the user to access their Twitter account
        [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            // Did user allow us access?
            if (granted == YES)
            {
                // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
                NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

                // Sanity check
                if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) 
                {
                    // Keep it simple, use the first account available
                    ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];

                    NSURL *url = 
                    [NSURL URLWithString:
                     @"https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json"];

                    //  Create a POST request for the target endpoint
                    TWRequest *request = 
                    [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url 
                                        parameters:nil 
                                     requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

                    //  self.accounts is an array of all available accounts; 
                    //  we use the first one for simplicity
                    [request setAccount:acct];

                    //  The "larry.png" is an image that we have locally
                    UIImage *image = (UIImage *)[dictionarydata valueForKey:@"image"];
                    NSLog(@"%@",image);
                    if (image!=nil) {

                        //  Obtain NSData from the UIImage 
                        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);


                        //  Add the data of the image with the 
                        //  correct parameter name, "media[]"
                        [request addMultiPartData:imageData 
                                         withName:@"media[]" 
                                             type:@"multipart/form-data"];

                        // NB: Our status must be passed as part of the multipart form data
                        NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",[dictionaryData valueForKey:@"firstname"],[dictionaryData valueForKey:@"lastname"],[dictionarydata valueForKey:@"title"]];

                        //  Add the data of the status as parameter "status"
                        [request addMultiPartData:[status dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                                         withName:@"status" 
                                             type:@"multipart/form-data"];
                        //  Perform the request.  
                        //    Note that -[performRequestWithHandler] may be called on any thread,
                        //    so you should explicitly dispatch any UI operations to the main thread 
                        [request performRequestWithHandler:
                         ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                             NSDictionary *dict = 
                             (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization 
                                              JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];

                             // Log the result
                             NSLog(@"%@", dict);

                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                 // perform an action that updates the UI...
                             });
                         }];
                    }else{
                        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"];
                        NSDictionary *p = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",[dictionaryData valueForKey:@"firstname"],[dictionaryData valueForKey:@"lastname"],[dictionarydata valueForKey:@"title"]], @"status",
                                           nil
                                           ];
                        TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc]
                                                  initWithURL:   url
                                                  parameters:    p
                                                  requestMethod: TWRequestMethodPOST
                                                  ];

                        // Post the request
                        [postRequest setAccount:acct];

                        // Block handler to manage the response
                        [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"Twitter response, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
                        }];
}
                }
            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do If you have been using Twitter framework:

```
NSString *statusesShowEndpoint = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
NSDictionary *params = @{@"status": @"Great101 - https://share.livefrom.me/p/md5mrCp"};

NSError *clientError;
NSURLRequest *request = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
                         URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                         URL:statusesShowEndpoint
                         parameters:params
                         error:&clientError];

if (request) {
    [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
     sendTwitterRequest:request
     completion:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                  NSData  *data,
                  NSError *connectionError) {
         if (data) {
             // handle the response data e.g.
             NSError *jsonError;
             NSDictionary *dicResponse = [NSJSONSerialization
                                           JSONObjectWithData:data
                                           options:0
                                           error:&jsonError];
             NSLog(@"%@",[dicResponse description]);
         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"Error code: %ld | Error description: %@", (long)[connectionError code], [connectionError localizedDescription]);
         }
     }];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", clientError);
}
```